# Running Multiple execution of Executable with parameterized command via Jemeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

All, i would like some help in resolving this issue.

PROBLEM : NEED The ability to run  console APP to be processed but without waiting for that one to finish, execute the others based on number of threads to be run as well as time wait

For example:

Application description:
someApp.exe  - This app calls with Parameter- Example someApp.exe  -I someinputfile -d typeofserveice -r  -i <some_input.json> -w 
This will connect to the service and post it to the service and wait for a response in set amount of wait time before timing out.

What I want to do:

1 Request
5 Request  - simultaneous    - want the ability to control this say every 15 second spawn that request until you get to 5 concurrent request
8, 16 etc

I don’t want to wait for one request to complete before trying the next request….

I started with OS Process Sampler

Problem here is two folds:

1. I can’t change the Request ID in the batch file
2. It is waiting for one Request to finish

What I tried

Multiple Thread Group with same command….. Different batch file for each……

[image]

Is it possible to use Beanshell or instead of Running Batch I can pass the same command that is in the batch file via OS PROCESS SAMPLE which I can control the variable names such as requestID etc….

cd C:\PFG_CLIENT_APP\SOMECLIENTAPPNAME\Debug
ClientApp.exe -d appigee -r 61129361 -i test_svc_input.json -w 700

-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see how these questions are connected to JMeter, it's all about Windows, command prompt and batch files.

1. `I can’t change the Request ID in the batch file` - you don't need to, just replace this `61129361` with `%1` in the batch file and you will be able to pass it as a parameter

   [image]
2. `It is waiting for one Request to finish` You can amend your command to contain [`START /W`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html), in this case it will start your batch file in a new window and wait for its termination. To suppress waiting on JMeter side you can set the timeout to a low value like 1 second (or whatever time it takes for your script/program to start)

   [image]

   The timeout will cause the sampler to fail, if you would rather like to have it as passed - add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of this request and configure it like:

   [image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri!!!! let me follow this instruction.

Comment: Dmitri T, thank you, i have another question.... don't know if i should raise another question or can i ask it here.....I have a Get Request which i am using http sampler and i am getting the results back, "{\"Status\": \"RECEIVED\", \"DllUrl\": \"\", \"Message\": \" \"}"  But i need to first Parse this extractor..... and wait until the status is COMPLETED....I am looking into While Controller, but need to figure out what i put in the Regex extractor and the while loop condition...